# How to reverse css animation on second click

Tags: jquery, css

I created an animation that draws and animates three lines.

1. top, from right to left
2. left, from top to bottom
3. bottom, from left to right.

The content wrapper is `display: none` and when click on `#btn` it displays and the line animates. I expect on second click line animation to reverse and the content wrapper should go back to `display: none`.

I tried the below code, but it didn't work. Can anybody give me some suggestions what to do?

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
    $('.content-wrapper').css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
  } else {
    $('.content-wrapper').css({
      'display': 'block'
    });
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

```css
.content-wrapper {
  display: none;
  width: 68.5%;
  height: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.l-top,
.l-left,
.l-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}

.l-top {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
  -webkit-animation-name: l-top;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
}

.l-left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1px;
  -webkit-animation-name: l-left;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
}

.l-bottom {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
  -webkit-animation-name: l-bottom;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes l-top {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    background: red;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes l-left {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    background: red;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes l-bottom {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    background: red;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn">btn</btn>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <span class="l-top"></span>
    <span class="l-left"></span>
    <span class="l-bottom"></span>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: try toggling a reverse class,class1 is `content-wrapper-in` the next class `content-wrapper-out` (the reverse class) set it, then set the display to none using `setInterval` at ex. `1000` ms (after the second class is set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using transitions instead of animations? I had to animate the content wrapper's width itself, so it's not really hidden but simply 0 width, but that's practically the same.

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('.content-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.content-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width .1s 1.2s;
}

.content-wrapper.open {
  width: 68.5%;
  transition: width .1s;
}

.l-top,
.l-left,
.l-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}

.content-wrapper .l-top {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  transition: width .4s .8s;
}

.content-wrapper.open .l-top {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .4s;
}

.content-wrapper .l-left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1px;
  height: 0;
  transition: height .4s .4s;
}

.content-wrapper.open .l-left {
  height: 100%;
  transition: height .4s .4s;
}

.content-wrapper .l-bottom {
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1px;
  transition: width .4s;
}

.content-wrapper.open .l-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  transition: width .4s .8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn">btn</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <span class="l-top"></span>
  <span class="l-left"></span>
  <span class="l-bottom"></span>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```